# How to fix this error when i using :first-child in emotion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I am using `Emotion` in `react`.

My elements:

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="one">1</span>
    <div class="two">2</div>
    <span class="three">3</span>
    <div class="four">4</div>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
    & > *:not(:first-child) {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

It has an error from `Emotion`:

```
The pseudo class ":first-child" is potentially unsafe when doing server-side rendering. Try changing it to ":first-of-type".
```

However, it was clear that even replacing `:first-child` with `:first-of-type` would not achieve the result I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered changing all `span` to `div` or vice versa?

As suggested by the name, `:first-of-type` only search for elements with the same type. Since you are mixing `div` and `span`, obviously it won't work.

BTW, unless you are doing SSR (e.g. using Next or Gatsby), you can safely ignore that warning.